# JSON not being parsed for validation when doing a POST request to Fastify

Tags: node.js, validation, routes, fastify, ajv

In my routes, I have the following:

```
const reservationSchema = {
  body: {
    type: 'object',
    required: ['in', 'out', 'guests', 'language', 'roomsSelected'],
    properties: {
      language: {
        type: 'string',
      },
      // ... several other property validations here
    }
  }
};

fastify.post(
  '/api/reservations/:slug',
  { schema: reservationSchema },
  reservationsController.addReservation
);
```

I send the POST request from React like this:

```
const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOSTNAME + '/api/reservations/' + property.slug, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
});
```

I can see that it is correctly sending JSON when I look at the request:

[image: screenshot]

However I receive the following response:

```json
{
  "statusCode":400,
  "error":"Bad Request",
  "message":"body should be object"
}
```

Am I missing something to automatically parse the POST body as an object in Fastify so I can validate it using a validation schema? Even in my `reservationsController.addReservation()` function I need to manually do `JSON.parse()` on `req.body`.

Answer (score 8):

From the [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) docs:

> Both request and response (and by extension the fetch() function), will try to intelligently determine the content type. A request will also automatically set a Content-Type header if none is set in the dictionary.

However, (at least in Chrome), when you send a JSON string, it **does not** intelligently determine that this string is JSON, and instead sends the `Content-Type` header as `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`. Since the server receives this `Content-Type` header, it assumes that you are sending a plan text string and therefore does not parse it as JSON.

To make the server automatically parse the body as JSON, you need to make sure to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. Like this:

```
const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOSTNAME + '/api/reservations/' + property.slug, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
});
```